# A poster with 300 faces

Tags: prints, software-recommendation, programming

Here is my problem. I have pictures of 300 people in JPG format that are numbered 1 to 300. In excel, I have 300 names in the same order. Now I must make a poster of 10 columns and 30 rows with each face and their name underneath. I have been Googling for 300 minutes and I am beginning to fear I have to paste every photo and name manually to a powerpoint slide...

Comment: What software do you have available? Can you use Photoshop for example?

Comment: I can get my hands on Adobe software but I have zero experience. Furthermore, I just have MS software and a macbook air to work on

Comment: 10 by 30 images might look strange. It looks like a requirement you have, but also consider 15 by 20. This is a 3 by 4 aspect ratio, which most cameras use for images. Having the images and the grid of images in the same ratio might be more visually pleasing. If you need tips on that sort of layout stuff, [graphicdesign.se] might be a good place to ask.

Comment: Thanks Null! I just gave the 10 by 30 as a quick example, just to make the challenge I am facing clear; a grid with many images and names

Comment: What output do you want?   There are loads of scripting options depending on your OS, you can do a quick/dirty find/replace on a directory listing to produce HTML for the quick & dirty approach, VBA in Microsoft Office can produce any office documents you want, the Adobe products have a JavaScript option... the list goes on.  

Bear in mind though - we'll tell you what you need to do not how to do it, or do it for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about scripting Excel and some other software, which doesn't seem very directly related to photography.

Comment: i would create an html and save it as pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can download ImageMagick for free from [imagemagick.org](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).  Then you can do this:

First, from excel, export your list of names into a "names.txt" file, one name per line.

Second, "label" each n.jpg with the n'th line in names.txt, using "sed" to extract the n'th line, creating a file called n.png:

```
for x in *.jpg
do
    n=`echo $x | sed -e s/.jpg//`
    magick $x -set label `sed -n -e "$n p" names.txt` $n.png
done
```

Finally, make your montage from the resulting n.png files:

```
magick montage -tile 10x30 -label %l *.png montage.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing what software tool you want to use, it's a bit difficult to provide an exact answer.  Here is the pseudocode way I'd do it.  Matlab, for one, could assemble the image, tho' it's hardly the best or fastest tool.

Let's pretend you've loaded the 300 names into an array of character strings, and have initialized a graphics frame. Then,

```
for j = 1:15
   for k = 1:20
      place_image(image[k + (k-1)*j]) AT location(x=j, y = k)
      write(name_array[k + (k-1)*j]) AT title_location(x=j, y = k)
  end
end
```

Here, you'd have preset the location increment from `(j,k)` to `(j,k+1)` as one image size, and preset `title_location` with respect to the current image area.

Answer (score -1):

Adobe InDesign would be best for this. Create a canvass and then using a Frame Tool (F) draw out a frame to the margins of the canvass (or the edges)- whilst still holding a mouse use arrow keys on keyboard to divide big frame into many cells. Then click on each cell and press Cntrl+D or Cmd+D to place images one by one. Press cmd+alt+shift+C to proportionally center each image inside the frame. Shouldn't take too long!

Comment: I'd be shocked if AiD didn't support a macro.  You really want to hit those keystrokes 300 times w/o a single error?